# IOS crash only in release

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a crash which I can't reproduce and I really don't understand the crashlog. I finally managed to symbolize the crashlog so it should be a bit useful. I only get the error when building for release (archiving and uploading to hockeyapp). Can anyone point me in the right direction? My objective-c and iOS knowledge is a bit lacking:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

___exceptionPreprocess + 122
_objc_exception_throw + 34
+[NSException raise:format:] + 108
-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 852
-[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 160
0x43a2e
-[UITableView _delegateViewForHeaderInSection:] + 36
___96-[UITableView _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]_block_invoke + 82
+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 68
-[UITableView _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:] + 542
-[UITableView _sectionHeaderViewWithFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:] + 58
-[UITableView _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 2374
-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2864
-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 182
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
__afterCACommitHandler + 128
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
___CFRunLoopDoObservers + 274
___CFRunLoopRun + 910
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
_CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
_GSEventRunModal + 132
_UIApplicationMain + 1436
0x28082
_tlv_initializer + 2
```

Btw, can I someone do a release build but still debug? Since I do nto get this error when debugging both on 2 different physical devices as well as any of the simulator ones.

Comment: Could be a Xib not correctly added to bundle (for some version?) since the issue seems to be occuring in a `[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]` call.

Comment: I have been removing some "unused" xib . Do where should I look for incorrectness?

Comment: I'd say that in a nib used for a headerView of a `UITableView` according to your crash log.

Comment: Check in your `project -> target(s) -> Build phases -> Copy bundle resources` if your deleted .xib file is still there

Comment: @Jasper I have 5 xib files and they all in the copy bundle resource list.

Comment: None of them are shown in red?

Comment: I do however have more .xib files in the project directory(folder structure) than is added to the project. Maybe it fetches those during debug but not release or something like that?

Comment: Check where you are initialising .xibs and if those are really added to your project, it probably has something to do with UITableView(Header) according to your crash log. Click on a .xib file and check the `File Inspector` on the right to see if its added to all targets where needed.

Comment: @Jasper all xib was added to the project. However I did restore all the removed xib files from source control and added  them to the project again and now it is working. Don't know which broke it and why there seem to be a cache with the files to they work on debug but not release. Thank you for your help. If you want to write an answer go ahead and I will accept it!

Comment: Maybe just a project clean might have fixed it :-) Glad to have been able to help!

Comment: @Jasper no clean folder didn't fix it. However a "Clean Build Folder… (Option+Shift+Command+K)" might have fixed it. Not available in menu though so I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Your crash report is not fully symbolicated. Actually the too addresses missing symbols point to code in your app. Especially the top address is where your code causes the app to crash. Also the crash is caused by an exception where iOS never shows the very helpful message. Add the HockeyApp SDK (and not only use it for distribution) and you will get fully symbolicated crash reports with the exception message too and you would already know where the bug in your code is.

Answer (score 1):

Debug builds have no optimisation enabled (-O0), whereas release builds have optimisation enabled (-O3 or -Os). 
You can just go into the build settings on Xcode in the Debug configuration and temporarily turn up the optimisation level - this will keep all the other debug goodies (symbols etc) but hopefully also flush out the release mode bug.

also, you can set release mode:

> 1.Go to "Project" command in an Xcode application menu and chose "Edit Scheme"(Shortcut: ⌘< )
>
> 2.Select "Run Project name" in left pane
>
> 3.In right pane, under "Info" tab change "Build Configuration" to "Release"

[image]

Comment: Very helpful tips, It did however crash as soon as it sort of tried to add itself to the device so I did not get much further more than being able to upload release version to the phone which I could start (without xcode attached) and try out and see if the problem was fixed.